# How to fetch records from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two database tables with `1 to M` relationship as below

CaseMaster (caseId, case#, title, ....)

CaseStages (stageId, caseId, stageName, ...., lawyerName,...)

Above relationship means that each case goes through multiple stages (Preliminary, Cassation, Execution etc.). In each stage, their can be different or no lawyer. I want to list all the cases (not stages) which never had a lawyer for any stage.

I tried to do this using `group by` statement on caseId, but don't know how to fetch only those cases which never had a lawyer.

[image]

Comment: share sample data and output

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your query using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` like following.

```
SELECT cm.caseid, 
       cm.[case#], 
       cm.title 
FROM   casemaster cm 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   casestages cs 
                   WHERE  cs.caseid = cm.caseid 
                          AND cs.lawyername IS NOT NULL)
```

If you really want to do it using `GROUP BY`, it can be done like following.

```
select cm.caseid,cm.title
from CaseMaster cm
inner join CaseStages cs on cs.caseid=cm.caseid
group by cm.caseid,cm.title
having sum(case when cs.lawyerName is null then 0 else 1 end)=0
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/ENGG71171)

Comment: works great. Just wondering if its possible to do the same with a group by clause?

Comment: @WAQ, i have updated the answer for GROUP BY, you can have a look

Answer (score 0):

use not in

```
 select t1.* from casemaster t1
 where  caseid not in ( select caseid from casestages t2 where 
                      t2.laywername is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "distinct keyword in your query to avoid duplicates.